# Получение сигнала. sigaction(). Недопонимание с сигналами

Tags: linux, c, signal

Допустим, что есть программа, которая при получении определенного сигнала печатает номер этого сигнала и `ID` процесса, откуда был послан сигнал. В коде это все выглядит примерно так:

Функция, которая используется как обработчик сигнала для функции `sigaction()`

```
void fun(int sig, siginfo_t *make, void *arg){
    printf("Received signal: %d\n", sig);
    printf("From process %u\n", make->si_pid);
    printf("Done from function\n");
}
```

И сам `main()`

```
int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction test;
    memset(&test, 0, sizeof(test));
    printf("I am process %i\n", getpid());

    test.sa_sigaction = &fun;
    test.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &test, NULL);

    sleep(100);
    printf("Done from main\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Работать данная программа будет с сигналом `SIGTERM`- сигнал для запроса завершения процесса. Как посмотреть вывод программы я напишу в конце поста, а сейчас хочу задать несколько вопросов:

1) Скажите, пожалуйста, для функции `sigaction()` создается отдельный процесс/поток? Просто не совсем понимаю, почему, когда я в main() вызываю данную функцию, то только при получении сигнала она исполняется, а не сразу, когда я ее вызвал.

2) Я не совсем понимаю смысл флага `SIGINFO`, но если я его не установлю, то ответ будет другим. Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего он нужен (программе/пользователю)

3) Почему, когда управление возвращается из функции `sigaction()` в функцию `main()`, то программа сразу выводит фразу `Done from main`, а не дожидается истечения `100` секунд после вызова функции `sleep()`. А если создается отдельный поток для `sigaction()`, тогда почему игнорируется `sleep()` после получения сигнала

Вывод программы:
запускаете данную программу и запоминаете число, которое выводит функция `printf()` в терминал, затем открываете другой терминал и пишете там такую команду

```
kill -SIGTERM <pid>
```

, где pid - это то число, которые вы запомнили.

p.s. Под Linux работает, под Windows не пробовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf нельзя вызывать внутри сигнала. Список [разрешенных функций внутри обработчика сигнала](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

1) текущий поток приостанавливается и в нем работает обработчик сигнала.

2) Когда сигнал пришел приложению, может быть не вся информация по этому сигналу доступной. И пользователю нужно вызывать sigwaitinfo(2) и sigtimedwait(2), чтобы получить ее. Если флаг SIGINFO выставить, то вся эта информация будет доступна сразу. Так как Вы выводите информацию о процессе, который послал сигнал, то лучше этот флаг выставить.

3) потому что получения сигнала умеет прерывать выполнение ряда функций (длинных функций). sleep входит в них. В манах [об этом явно и написано](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html)

> sleep() causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number of
>          real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed or **until a signal
>          arrives** which is not ignored.