# Некорректно работает обработчик сигнала

Tags: linux, c

Вот я создаю обработчик:

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler=handler;
sigaction(SIGINT,&act,NULL);
```

Сама функция-обработчик `handler`:

```
void handler()
{
   reset_canonical_mode();
   system("clear");
   exit(1);

}
```

Когда я нажимаю CTR + C по идее должна вызваться функция `handler`, она вызывается, но работает не пойми каким образом, функция же `reset_canonical_mode();` вообще не вызывается. Почему так происходит? Объясните пожалуйста, как мне тогда в ответ на сигнал SIGINT очистить терминал, вывести сообщение и закрыть процесс?

Comment: Как вы знаете, что она не вызывается? Ну и вообще читать документацию полезно: функции делятся на signal-safe и, как не трудно догадаться, на signal-**un**safe. Более, чем уверен, что `system()` — signal-**un**safe. Да и таких в принципе подавляющее большинство.

Comment: @0andriy, Читал я четверть статейки в opennet, что-то кое-как понял, но не выдержав пошел читать про сигналы на хабре - https://habr.com/ru/post/141206/ . Предположил я что она не вызывается потому-что она не срабатывает. Что значат эти сигнал сейфы?

Comment: Ну вы же видите как ваша программа «работает», вот это и есть *unsafe*, которое в UB перетекает.

Comment: Комментарии почитайте по приведённой вами же ссылке.

Comment: @0andriy, хорошо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение сигнала. sigaction(). Недопонимание с сигналами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793957/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-sigaction-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Пользуйтесь внутри `handler()` только [signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) функциями. Т.е. для вывода сообщения (и эскейп-последовательности очистки экрана вызывайте [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html))

Comment: @avp, спасибо вам)) А не объясните еще, зачем в обработчике в параметры указывать переменную типа int : `void handler(int g)`?

Comment: @avp, и как я с помощью write запишу команду в терминал(как я заменю system)?

Comment: [ESC[2J Clear screen and home cursor](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html) / Т.е. `static char clrscr[] = "\e[1;1H\e[2J"; write(1, clrscr, sizeof(clrscr) - 1);` / (если fd терминала отлично от stdout, то подставьте его в `write()`)

Comment: `void handler(int g)` -- параметр это номер сигнала, который вызвал исполнение обработчика

Comment: ********************** обработчик, извиняюсь за свои "а посяму??? а как???"Но сам я долго буду искать решение того, что пытаюсь понять как работает. Поэтому, а как мне тогда перевести терминал обратно в канонический режим при поступлении сигнала? То есть обратно включить отображение введенных символов в терминал и т.д. Я вызываю tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&standart_settings) в обработчике, но она почему-то не выполняется, хотя без обработчика она работает

Comment: Это надо делать в main loop. Также почитайте документацию на `atexit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основной принцип, при написании обработчика сигнала - не делать в нём **ничего**, что может вызвать задержку или даже зависание программы. Почему - это отдельный вопрос.

Поэтому, все такие действия желательно вынести из обработчика. К примеру, как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// Флаг необходимости сделать некоторое действие
int command = 0;

// Обработчик сигнала
void handler()
{
   command = 1; // Сделай это нечто!

}

// Выполняет некоторое действие принажатии Ctrl/C
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler=handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&act,NULL);


    while(1) {
        // Предполагается. что здесь у Вас какая-то полезная работа
        sleep(1);
        if (command != 0) {
            printf("Выполняем нужное действие\n");
            // reset_canonical_mode(); - Так ?
            command = 0;
        } else {
            printf("Думаю...\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Только обратите внимание, что т.к. программа перехватывает нажатие Ctrl/C, то так её остановить не удастся. Придётся открыть ещё один терминал, выдать в нём команду *ps ax*, найти *pid* запущенной программы и прибить её путём *kill -9 "pid программы"*

Comment: все равно не выполняется reset_canonical_mode

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич - Что значит *не выполняется* ? Не вызывается эта функция или она вызывается, но не делает того, что Вы от неё ожидаете?

Comment: все хорошо, просто я протупил) Спасибо за ответ, все ясно:-)